# Allowing mixed content http requests

Tags: iis, mixed-content

I have a website which can be accessed only trough `https://` , but i'm using external API's which does not have `https` support. I know it's possible to allow mixed content on the browser level, but is it possible to allow it on the IIS level?

Comment: Given [this (similar one)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37080972/5045126) answer, you won't be able to do this

Answer (score 0):

Consider rewriting the requests to https, http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: This won't help because the external api doesn't support https requests. I need some way to send http request from https website, if this is possible.