# Allow Mixed Content From Specific Domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https

my website runs on https , my chat server is on another domain which doesnt have https and i have to connect my website to chat server by loading socket.io from chat server

```
<script src="http://chetserver.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

but of curse i get

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/chat' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://chetserver.com/socket.io/socket.io.js'. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

im probabely going to move chat server on https as well but , is there anyway to  allow mixed content only from `chetserver.com`  using utaccess (or any other method )?

Comment: See this Q&A also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043719/how-can-i-allow-mixed-contents-http-with-https-using-content-security-policy-m - I think that that is what you're probably looking to use.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanx , but i want to load resources from http into https domain ... its not about detect  protocol  if i put `src=//chetserver.com` it'll change to `src=https://chetserver.com` which wont work bcuz `chetserver.com` doesn't have https

Comment: Welcome. I added another comment/link; did you see that one also?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanx second link is apparently my answer ... which is i cant do that !

Comment: you can't use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` ?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner that meta will convert http to https, which wont work because the target server doesn't support https